# How do I grant IIS APPPOOL\Orchard access to SQL Server 2012 Developer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I tried to install Orchard CMS to it's own web site, IIS create a web pool called Orchard. After supplying a connection string of

```
Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Orchard;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

The Orchard setup program gave me an error that

```
 Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\Orchard'
```

Try as I may, I cannot find or get SQL Server to accept this user name. What am I supposed to do? For now I just installed Orchard with an internal, i.e. SQL CE database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 USE [Master]
 GO
 CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\Orchard] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Orchard]
 USE [Orchard]
 CREATE USER [IIS APPPOOL\Orchard] FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\Orchard]
```

I use IIS AppPool accounts all the time to access SQL databases, often I put them in a Windows Group first and then use the Windows Group in SQL-Server. This makes it easier to change pool names.

Comment: Thanks. I have become too dependent on using the GUI for DB admin and sometimes it really comes up short compare to T-SQL.